# What does __init__(self) mean in Python?

Tags: python, init, self

I am currently studying Python and I have seen in many source codes that uses **init**(self) but I do not know about it.

I'm a newbie so please explain it easily.

Answer (score 0):

self is like the 'this' keyword in JavaScript. 
If you have

```
def __init__(self):
    self.foo = 'bar'
```

that object will now have a .foo that is equal to a string of bar.

Passing self in elsewhere is used too. If you want your object to have a method

```
def myMethod(self, parameter1, parameter2):
    #do stuff
```

self is needed so that the method is attached to the created objects

Comment: Thanks so much, but I do not know what method means.
Is it something similar to functions?

Comment: It's a function attached to an object. I'm guessing that you saw the code inside of a class. Every object that is created from that class, will have those attached methods that you create. I wasn't sure if you'd also seen self used there, but you'll come across that too.